# Which version of Eclipse supports J2ME application development?

Tags: java-me, eclipse-plugin

Trying to develop a J2ME application, but I am unable to configure J2ME in Eclipse (Juno) with Java ME SDK v. 3.2. The emulator will not even run with NetBeans 7.2.  How can I get this configured properly?

Comment: Please help, as i have tried every way possible to make a simple j2me application on netbeans v 7.2 as well as eclipse(juno).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly why, but `MTJ` does not run with [`Juno`](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/). If you like `Eclipse` try it with [`Indigo`](http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/).

Comment: Also the emulator doesn't run when working on Netbeans v 7.2 I have tried loading EclipseME plugin in eclipse but i fail to configure it completely. Is there any source that can tell me what steps to apply to configure J2ME plugin in eclipse or on Netbeans?

Comment: You should use MTJ instead of EclipseME. Here it is, step-by-step: https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/how_to_integrate_java_me

Answer (score 0):

do the following steps:

1. go to help->install new software
2. click on add tab
3. in the name text field give "eclipse me update site"
4. in the url give "http://eclipseme.org/updates"
5. install the software
6. then you can find j2me installed in your eclipse juno

   now integrating sun wtk emulator with juno

   1.go to file ->new ->project->j2me

   2.next we need to import devices for running midlets

   3.click on the import tab

   specify the path for the wtk

   click refresh button select the devices

   4.try to build an midlet applications